# JS array of objects, group values by timestamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have array of objects like:

```
var arr = 
[{timestamp: "2019-04-15T11:00:00.000Z", value:true},
{timestamp: "2019-04-15T12:00:00.000Z", value: false},
{timestamp: "2019-04-15T13:00:00.000Z", value: true},
{timestamp: "2019-04-15T14:00:00.000Z", value: true},
{timestamp: "2019-04-15T15:00:00.000Z", value: true},
{timestamp: "2019-04-15T16:00:00.000Z", value: false},
{timestamp: "2019-04-15T17:00:00.000Z", value: true},
{timestamp: "2019-04-15T18:00:00.000Z", value: true}...] etc
```

for 24 hours. 
I need to show times for starting and finishing true value, from value false should be separate group of times:

For exp.: Times on: 11, 13-15, 17-18.

is it possible to sort like this array?

At the moment I am getting array like this:
Times on: 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18.

```
const onValues = arr.filter(item => item.output === true );
const onValuesTimes = onValues.map(a => (moment(a.timestamp).format('HH:mm')));
```

Comment: please add the wanted result (as data).

Comment: I am not sure for this, I need to display this in front end as mentioned.

Comment: it is unclear if you like to get an array of values or joint values with a minus sign, or what ever.

Comment: I need to get true values in groups if they are separated by false, this should be separate group , and then show first and last value in this group. Like in my sample times on: 11, 13 -15.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the timestamp for values and build atart and end items, join these items and join the result.

```js
var array = [{ timestamp: "2019-04-15T11:00:00.000Z", value: true }, { timestamp: "2019-04-15T12:00:00.000Z", value: false }, { timestamp: "2019-04-15T13:00:00.000Z", value: true }, { timestamp: "2019-04-15T14:00:00.000Z", value: true }, { timestamp: "2019-04-15T15:00:00.000Z", value: true }],
    result = array
        .reduce((r, b, i, { [i - 1]: a }) => {
            if (!b.value) return r;
            if (a && a.value) {
                r[r.length - 1][1] = b.timestamp.slice(11, 16);
            } else {
                r.push([b.timestamp.slice(11, 16)]);
            }
            return r;
        }, [])
    .map(a => a.join('-'))
    .join(', ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a mil Nina, that's work perfectly. Just I cant mark right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: You could use my [ts-iterable-functions](https://github.com/biggyspender/ts-iterable-functions) library: The [`groupAdjacent`](https://github.com/biggyspender/ts-iterable-functions/blob/master/src/transformers/groupAdjacent.ts) function is made for this

```js
const {pp, groupAdjacent, _map, map, _count, _single, _first, _last, filter} = 
   tsIterableFunctions
var arr = [
  {timestamp: "2019-04-15T11:00:00.000Z", value: true},
  {timestamp: "2019-04-15T12:00:00.000Z", value: false},
  {timestamp: "2019-04-15T13:00:00.000Z", value: true},
  {timestamp: "2019-04-15T14:00:00.000Z", value: true},
  {timestamp: "2019-04-15T15:00:00.000Z", value: true},
  {timestamp: "2019-04-15T16:00:00.000Z", value: false},
  {timestamp: "2019-04-15T17:00:00.000Z", value: true},
  {timestamp: "2019-04-15T18:00:00.000Z", value: true}
]

const q=pp(
  arr,
  groupAdjacent(
    x => x.value,
    x => x,
    (key,elements) => ({
      key,
      values : _map(elements, e => moment(e.timestamp).utc().hour())
    })
  ),
  filter(x => x.key), // == true
  map(
      x => `${ _first(x.values) }-${ _last(x.values) + 1 }`
  )
)
console.log([...q])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ts-iterable-functions@2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment"></script>
```

Comment: Just one more question. Would be possible to print instead of 15:00, next value 16:00? that print would be 11, 13-16, 17-19 ?

Comment: @KristinaAs Yes. So, logically that should be 11-12, 13-16, 17-19? See my edit.